# Is there any PythonForm ? to automate Sin[] to math.sin()?

Tags: output-formatting, python

`Sin[]` does not exist in Python and while I can do `FortranForm` and similar things,  I do not know of any `PythonForm`, is there anything built-in to convert an expression to Python?

Of course I can make rules like `Sin[a_]->math.sin(a)` but is going to be tedious and maybe somebody (at Wolfram) did this already?

I think the question is sufficiently different from this one [85445/convert-mathematica-math-expression-form-to-python-math-expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85445/convert-mathematica-math-expression-form-to-python-math-expression)

Answer that I take from @masterxilo and I will keep updating as more known functions appear under my radar

```
PythonForm~SetAttributes~HoldAll
PythonForm[Sin[x_]] := StringTemplate["math.sin(``)"]@PythonForm@x
PythonForm[Cos[x_]] := StringTemplate["math.cos(``)"]@PythonForm@x
PythonForm[Log[x_]] := StringTemplate["math.log(``)"]@PythonForm@x
PythonForm[Rational[a_, b_]] := 
StringTemplate["(``/``)"][PythonForm@a, PythonForm@b]
PythonForm[Pi] := ToString["math.pi"]
PythonForm[Times[a_, b_]] := 
StringTemplate["(`` * ``)"][PythonForm@a, PythonForm@b]
PythonForm[Power[a_, b_]] := 
StringTemplate["(``**``)"][PythonForm@a, PythonForm@b]
PythonForm[Plus[a_, b_]] := 
StringTemplate["(``+``)"][PythonForm@a, PythonForm@b]
PythonForm[x_] := ToString@x;
PythonForm[f_Symbol[args___]] := 
StringTemplate["``(``)"][ToString@f, PythonForm@args]
PythonForm[args___] := (PythonForm /@ {args})~StringRiffle~", ";
```

Comment: you actually cant do `->math.sin()` because mathematica will take it as a dot product.  You can do something like  `->mathdotsin()` and fix it later with a string replace. Quite a hack though.

Comment: yes, `Dot[]` might stand in your way. For now I am doing an `InputForm` of everything and then replacing in the python editor `. ->.`,`^ ->**`, `[ -> (` and `]->)` .. awful but works, I was hoping in something more classy ...

Comment: Also related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85817/prepare-mathematica-output-to-be-parsed-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I where to do this manually, I would start with

```
PythonForm~SetAttributes~HoldAll
(*known symbols*)
PythonForm[Sin[x_]] := StringTemplate["math.sin(``)"]@PythonForm@x
PythonForm[Times[a_, b_]] := 
 StringTemplate["(`` * ``)"][PythonForm@a, PythonForm@b]
(*fallback*)
PythonForm[x_] := ToString@x; 
PythonForm[f_Symbol[args___]] := 
 StringTemplate["``(``)"][ToString@f, PythonForm@args]
PythonForm[args___] := (PythonForm /@ {args})~StringRiffle~", ";

PythonForm[Sin[2 * Sin[x] * 4 * f[x, y]]]
```

> `"math.sin((2 * (math.sin(x) * (4 * f(x, y)))))"`

Comment: You can probably leverage `ToString@FortranForm` to do some of the work.

Comment: I am editing my question to add the list of (*known symbols*) I have added so far. It should be noticed that this function cannot evaluate things like `%` because of the `HoldAll` I presume.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at my solution to this problem, at:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144200/48312. I also prepared a Mathematica package for handling this at https://github.com/gwiederhecker/ToPython.

Comment: Are those questions duplicates? (don't have time to read everything now and it seems you did it so I'm asking :)) p.s. we try to avoid link-only answers. Could you show an input with OP's case and the output generated by your function?

Comment: @kuba I would say so.

Comment: @bobthechemist thanks.