# Python compatible fortran form for complex numbers

Tags: complex, formatting, python, fortran

I am trying to use the Mathematica output of a complicated expression as input for python. As suggested in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85449), the `FortranForm` of an expression already comes close. However, the FortranForm of the complex number 1i is

```
FortranForm[1I]

(0,1)
```

which would be a tuple in python and not a complex number. How do I convert these expressions to complex numbers? In Python, 1i would be `1j`. I don't know if this is possible directly. Alternatively, complex numbers can be generated by calling the constructor `complex(a, b)`, where `a` is the real part and `b` is the imaginary part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `StringExpression` to match `(x, y)` patterns:

```
ClearAll[format] ;
format[rules_][expression_] := FixedPoint[
    StringReplace[rules], 
    ToString[FortranForm[expression]]
] ;

rules = {
    " " -> "",
    "+-" -> "-",
    "(" ~~ A:NumberString ~~ "," ~~ B:NumberString ~~ ")" :> StringTemplate["(`A`+`B`j)"][<|"A" -> A, "B" -> B|>]
} ;

expression = 1I + (2 + 3I) x + (3.1 - 0.1I)/x^2;
format[rules][expression]
(* "(0+1j)+(3.1-0.1j)/x**2+(2+3j)*x" *)
```